# Euler products without meromorphic continuation

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, euler-product

For every prime number $p$ fix a natural number $n_p$ with
$$
C\frac{p+1}2\le n_p\le C(p+1)
$$
for some constant $C>0$, independent of $p$.
The product
$$
F(s)=\prod_p\frac1{(1-p^{-s})^{n_p}}
$$
converges for $\mathrm{Re}(s)>2$. Is it true that such an Euler product cannot be meromorphically continued to the entire complex plane?

Comment: Have you tried special cases? E.g. $C = 1$ and $n_p = p$?

Comment: yes, I did. The case $ n_p=p$ satisfies the claim.

Comment: What do you get when applying the argument [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275706/does-this-product-have-analytic-continuation/275723#275723) ?